# Terrain Modelling

Tags: modeling

all. I am new to Blender. I have modeled a terrain by joining the edges of different contour lines which I imported from a DXF file. However, I have no idea how to continue creating a small hill on top of a closed polygon or surface. Next, I would like also to know whether there is any tutorial that I could refer to in order to know how to place a road nicely on the terrain surface. Please find the Blender file if needed. Thank you.

[image]
[image]
[enter link description here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AndATj6-RFHNhQ6phBGk54ZeZgt7?e=2q1apW)

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of the question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The hill**

For your small hill, I'd use Loop tools. It's an add-on that comes with your standard Blender.

[image]

Select two layers of vertices and Bridge them.

[image]

It's wise to subdivide longer edges since Looptools Bridge will not handle them great in this situation.

[image]

**The road**

As for your road, you could use a bunch of modifiers for that. Mainly Shrinkwrap, and a few others that increase the detail of the mesh geometry (more vertices) to help Shrinkwrap work better (give it more vertices to work with).

First something like this:
[image]

And then move the road above the hill (z-axis only) and press ALT+C and convert it to a mesh. (You could apply a Subdivision modifier first for more mesh geometry)
[image]

And finally apply Shrinkwrap (and some other modifiers to make it look a little bit nicer) The road is now projected on to the mountain surface from a top down perspective. (Note how the "Mode:" is set to Project.)

[image]

The road is shaped a bit funny where there is no mountain underneath it; that might need some manual editing/tweaking I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Go to EDIT MODE, select two vertices and press F (to create an edge or face).
Continue pressing F to generate all the faces (vertices have to be aligned).

**STEP 1:**
[image]

**STEP 2:**
[image]

probably there is also a better and automated way with extensions. did you look for them?